# Webpack variable output path

Tags: webpack

I would like to use variable output paths similar to [file-loader](https://github.com/webpack/file-loader#filename-template-placeholders) one.

```
var webpackConfig = {
  context: path.join(__dirname, './app'),
  entry: {
    background: './background/background.js',
    popup: './popup/popup.js'
  },
  output: {
    path: path.join(__dirname, './dist'),
    filename: '[path][name].js'
  },
};
```

Any clue how to make this work?

#### Edit:

In detail I want the following result.

```
app/background/background.js 
  -> dist/background/background.js

app/popup/popup.js 
  -> dist/popup/popup.js
```

Comment: Does your example not work?

Comment: No it does't because there is no `[path]` placeholder :(

Comment: perhaps you are looking for `publicPath`? that will be prepended to your output paths

Answer (score 0):

The example you provided should just work – http://webpack.github.io/docs/configuration.html#output-filename

> `output.filename` The filename of the entry chunk as relative path
>   inside the output.path directory.
>
> `[name]` is replaced by the name of the chunk.
>
> `[hash]` is replaced by the hash of the compilation.
>
> `[chunkhash]` is replaced by the hash of the chunk.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this :

```
var webpackConfig = {
  entry: {
    background: './background/background.js',
    popup: './popup/popup.js'
  },
  output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, './dist'),
    filename: '[name]/[name].js'
  },
};
```

Answer (score 0):

For those who still have the same problem, for this specific problem, all you need to do is to use the below entry and output objects:

```js
var webpackConfig = {
  context: path.join(__dirname, './app'),
  entry: {
    'background/background': './background/background.js',
    'popup/popup': './popup/popup.js'
  },
  output: {
    path: path.join(__dirname, './dist'),
    filename: '[name].js'
  },
};
```